# What do you think 'it' means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Besides, making Ooho has a climate benefit, as **it** does not cause the CO2 emissions that the bottle manufacturing process does.

What does **it** mean?

1. Ooho
2. Making Ooho

Answer (score 4):

**It** here would mean *"making Ooho"* as it is compared to the manufacturing process of bottles.
As only similar things can be compared, hence two making/manufacturing processes are compared here.

Answer (score 1):

It is a *nicely drafted complex structured* sentence here. Let's break it down

> Besides,

Synonyms - *apart from (that)*, *other than (that)*.

This implies that this sentence **has** past statements, which are/should be based on **a** topic.

What's the topic then?

> making Ooho has a climate benefit

So, It could either be "making Ooho" *(the process)*, "Ooho" *(the thing/product)*, "climate" *(in general)* or "climate benefit" *(as a topic)*

> as **it** does not cause the CO2 emissions

Fill in all the options given above:

- as **making Ooho** does not cause the CO2 emissions *(makes sense)*
- as **Ooho** does not cause the CO2 emissions *(makes sense) {Considering singular}*
- as **climate** does not cause the CO2 emissions *(do not make sense)*
- as **climate benefit** does not cause the CO2 emissions *(do not make sense)*

> that the bottle manufacturing process does.

for this comparison to work the former choice should also be a process, *as the bottle manufacturing process.* Thus leaving us with the choice **`it`** as **`making Ooho`**
:D